# 403 Forbidden Error adding an event to a Google Calendar

Tags: android, google-api, google-calendar-api

Used the code from [ https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/create-events ] last month to add an event to a Google Calendar from an Android app and it worked. Now each time I attempt to add an event I get this error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
W/System.err: {
W/System.err:   "code" : 403,
W/System.err:   "errors" : [ {
W/System.err:     "domain" : "global",
W/System.err:     "message" : "Forbidden",
W/System.err:     "reason" : "forbidden"
W/System.err:   } ],
```

I tried looking for similar questions here but could not find an answer. Any ideas or direction to an answer on this page or another?

Answer (score 1):

Limits and quotas protect the Google infrastructure from an automated process that uses the Calendar Resource API in an inappropriate way. Excessive requests from an API might result from a harmless typo, or may result from an inefficiently designed system that makes needless API calls. Regardless of the cause, blocking traffic from a specific source once it reaches a certain level is necessary for the overall health of the Google Apps system. It ensures that one developer's actions cannot negatively impact the larger community.

In the unlikely event that your API request fails, you'll receive an HTTP status code response. A status code of 403 has error information about incorrect input, and an HTTP status code of 503 has error information indicating which API quotas have been exceeded. These responses allow your custom application to detect these errors and take appropriate action.

The maximum number of calendar resources per account is 10,000.

For more information follow this link:   https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/calendar-resource/limits

Comment: Thank you. Limits and quotas seem all good. I figured out that using [event.setEndTimeUnspecified(true);] caused the error.