# calendar ERROR 403: Forbidden

Tags: google-calendar-api

When I use Google Calendar APIs calendar.events.delete and calendar.events.update, you do not have permission to execute this method.response 403 Forbidden, but I have given the permission "https://www.googleapis.com/auth /calendar", please help me, thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[403 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34969010/403-forbidden-error-adding-an-event-to-a-google-calendar?rq=1) happens when you are hitting the current quota limit.

As per [google support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en),

> Google Calendar puts certain limits in place to protect our users and
>   infrastructure from abusive behavior. When these limits are reached by
>   a user, Google Calendar will go into read-only mode for that user, and
>   all edit actions will fail for a certain period of time. Most users
>   will never hit these limits, as they are well above the activity level
>   of a typical Calendar user.

To help you [handle the errors](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors), resolutions have been stated in the documentation.